# D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC::MipLODBias vs ID3D11DeviceContext::SetResourceMinLOD

Tags: directx, directx11, level-of-detail

When implementing a max-texture-detail functionality for a game, which approach is better to use, out of:

- Setting the `D3D11_SAMPLER_DESC::MipLODBias` value of a sampler state object, or,
- Setting the min resource LOD of each texture resource with `ID3D11DeviceContext::SetResourceMinLOD()`?

I'm thinking it's probably the second option, because using `SetResourceMinLOD()` means that only the relevant subresource will be uploaded to the video memory, correct?

If that is the case, I assume that setting `SetResourceMinLOD()` will cause Direct3D to remove unused detail levels from video memory (if necessary) if they're already on there?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetResourceMinLOD : For Direct3D 11, this functionality is extended from the sampler to the entire resource. Therefore, the application can specify the highest-resolution mip level of a resource that is available for access. This restricts the set of mip levels that are required to be resident in GPU memory, thereby saving memory.